# В чём различие `_physics_process` и просто `_process` в GDScript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

Часто в играх на Godot Engine вижу примерно такой код:

```
...

func _physics_process(delta):
    ...

func _process(delta):
    ...

...
```

Но в чём различие этих двух функций? Когда я сам попробовал написать один код в `_process` всё работает Ok, и если я перенесу этот код в `_physics_process` то все тоже работает нормально.

**Но в чём-же различие этих двух функций?**

Comment: посмотрите [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/1077522)

Comment: Помимо упомянутых в вышеуказанной ссылке различий, _physics_process может выполняться в отдельном потоке, если включена соответствующая опция в настройках проекта

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов спасибо, можете написать ответ. :)